# htaccess simple rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've never did rewrite rules and everything I try out and find at google doesn't work. Especially creating multiple rewrite rules is hard for me because I don't know how the right syntax is and how a proper implementation looks like (1 Rewrite Condition or multiple and similar questions).

Thus I would be happy to get a result for my following try:

https://www.domain.com/our_accounts.php -> https://www.domain.com/accounts

The http -> https rule is already working. Maybe there is also the problem with my rewrite rules because I may need to add them before my https rules ?? I hope you guys can help me with this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # First rewrite to HTTPS:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Rules for readable URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^accounts$ /our_accounts.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your htacess file this way. I also condensed the HTTP and www to one rewrite rule. Just replace `yoursite.com` with your real site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
     # First rewrite to HTTPS and redirect www:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^our_accounts.php$ /accounts [R=301,L]

    # Rules for readable URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works fine like the old one so far, but the rewrite rule of the file "our_accounts.php" to the virtual folder "accounts" still doesn't work. I tried basically everything is it possible that this just doesn't work for me because of any settings or something ? By the way rewriting from http->https works, index.php to the root directy works also fine.

Comment: `doesn't work` is not helpful. What is it not doing or what error are you getting? Basically what's the result. That works for me. Clear your browser cache and try.

Comment: Also what is the URL you are actually trying in the browser?

Comment: Ok I am sorry, I try to describe it more exactly. With doesn't work i mean the page is getting called normmaly with filename.php in the addressbar. The domain name is https://www.lol-accs.com -> press on accounts and you will see it. I tried it with a new chrome privacy window.

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood you and I have it backwards. Most people don't want to redirect a file to a directory. It's usually the other way around. See my update. Just reverse the rule

Comment: Oh my godness with that sentence you helped me so much. My intention just was it to have a readable url in the browserbar which is accessible from outside as well. I never thought about changing my navigation links instead of redirecting the .php file to the url. And that was the reason why all solutions "hasn't worked" for me. Thanks so much!